# Why don't CSS floats respect CSS3 columns?

Tags: html, css

I have some float:left divs inside a CSS3 column layout. The divs don't always respect the column-width property. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/upzkeLxc/

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='content w1 h1 c1'><span>One</span></div>
    <div class='content w3 h3 c2'><span>Two</span></div>
    <div class='content w3 h3 c3'><span>Three</span></div>
    <div class='content w3 h3 c4'><span>Four</span></div>
    <div class='content w1 h3 c5'><span>Five</span></div>
    <div class='content w2 h2 c6'><span>Six</span></div>
    <div class='content w2 h2 c7'><span>Seven</span></div>
    <div class='content w2 h2 c8'><span>Eight</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.c1 { background-color: red; }
.c2 { background-color: green; }
.c3 { background-color: blue; }
.c4 { background-color: yellow; }
.c5 { background-color: magenta; }
.c6 { background-color: cyan; }
.c7 { background-color: wheat; }
.c8 { background-color: rose; }

.w1 { width: 240px; }
.w2 { width: 120px; }
.w3 { width: 80px; }

.h1 { height: 240px; }
.h2 { height: 120px; }
.h3 { height: 80px; }

.container, .content {
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

.container {
    -webkit-column-width: 240px;
    -moz-column-width: 240px;
    column-width: 240px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;

}

.content {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the results on Google Chrome (at a certain width):

[image: Floating divs inside CSS column layout]

The column width **should** be the width of the red 'One' square, but 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' end up alongside, where I thought they should be below.

Does anyone have any ideas of CSS magic that will make those boxes respect the column widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guesing this is due to columns not being finalised or fully implemented yet.

Here's a fix that will get around the issue ...

Add an extra wrapper in the html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
        <div class='content w1 h1 c1'><span>One</span></div>
        <div class='content w3 h3 c2'><span>Two</span></div>
        <div class='content w3 h3 c3'><span>Three</span></div>
        <div class='content w3 h3 c4'><span>Four</span></div>
        <div class='content w1 h3 c5'><span>Five</span></div>
        <div class='content w2 h2 c6'><span>Six</span></div>
        <div class='content w2 h2 c7'><span>Seven</span></div>
        <div class='content w2 h2 c8'><span>Eight</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set the width of that wrapper to the width of your column:

```
.content-wrapper {
    width: 240px;
}
```

Explanation - the additional wrapper enforces the width restriction you need, but it itself should still obey the column flow rules.

Answer (score 1):

Column-width property does not define the width of the element but the width of each column of text within it.

For more details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-width.asp

The "classic" width is enough for you.

```
.container {
    width: 240px;        
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upzkeLxc/2/

Comment: I do still want the flow across the columns, it's just this weird behaviour that Two/Three/Four are not obeying the column width.

Comment: You can't... and the behaviour is right. Please see the page I linked in my answer ;)

Comment: The left-floating blocks ARE flowing with the columns, if you resize my original example, you will see it works most of the time.

Comment: Sure, becouse they haven't more space. What I mean is: column-width DOES NOT define the width of an element, or the max-width of its child. There is the **width** property for this! Use it!

Comment: The widths of the contents are defined by their own separate widths. The w1/w2/w3/h1/h2/h3 classes give those contents their widths, which are obeyed nicely. And the column-width for the overall column is obeyed MOST of the time, but the divs sometimes overflow into the column gap.

Comment: Upvoting because you are right, this does fix it, but doesn't preserve the columns as the other answer does. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `column-width` property doesn't define the exact width of each column. It defines the minimum width of the column. Basing on this value, the browser decides the number of the columns to create, and then evenly distributes the available width of the container between them. So, for example, if the container width is 900px, `column-width:240px` will mean that the browser makes 3 columns (maximum number of 240px-wide columns that fit into 900px) and their actual width will be 300px (assuming `column-gap:0`).